# Create website conf with 2 virtual hosts

Tags: wordpress, apache, virtual, host

I want to know if it's possible to have one apache website conf file with two vhost inside ?

More clearly :

For now if I access my website like this : XX.XX.XXX.XX I reach my wordpress folder.
Now, I want to access another folder like this : XX.XX.XXX.XX/interface

Is it possible to do it in the same conf file ?

Here is mine actually :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress/

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/wordpress/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If that `/interface` directory isn't inside `/var/www/wordpress` you'll need to set up an alias or RewriteRule for it.

Comment: Do you have a link with more information about aliases ? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html scroll down to **Files Outside the DocumentRoot** - or you can use `mod_rewrite` : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this :)